# Requesting payment information from a payment service (Google Pay, Apple Pay, Paypal) via API for use in a python applet

Tags: python, flask, applepay, payment-processing, google-pay

Ive been working on an idea for a flask applet for tracking my personal spending and am looking to request my payment history in a similar manner to Apple Pay, Google Pay and PayPal. I am looking for a way to import the data associated with a list of these payments via API to Python so it can be plotted and have been unable to locate an API that fulfills these needs. Does anyone know what my best path forward is?